# replace 'Decimal' from a list generated from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

input_list is generated from pandas dataframe. I am looking to replace all such entries at once in pandas dataframe.

```
input_list = {'borrower_master_id': 1000, 'attribute_derived_master_id': 100, 'year_id': 2018, 'quarter_id': 1.0, 'month_id': None, 'param1_value': Decimal('3.00'), 'param2_value': Decimal('223.00'), 'param3_value': None, 'param4_value': None, 'param5_value': None, 'formula_expression': 'param1+param2', 'attrib_type': 'Actual', 'derived_attrib_value': 226.0, 'is_active': True}

expected_list = {'borrower_master_id': 1000, 'attribute_derived_master_id': 100, 'year_id': 2018, 'quarter_id': 1.0, 'month_id': None, 'param1_value': 3.0, 'param2_value': 223 'param3_value': None, 'param4_value': None, 'param5_value': None, 'formula_expression': 'param1+param2', 'attrib_type': 'Actual', 'derived_attrib_value': 226.0, 'is_active': True}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? You will lose information by converting the values to int. Can you explain the problem you want to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary comprehension conditioning on the data type:

```
input_list = {k:(float(v) if isinstance(v, Decimal) else v) for k,v in input_list.items()}
```

```
input_list
>>>
{'borrower_master_id': 1000,
 'attribute_derived_master_id': 100,
 'year_id': 2018,
 'quarter_id': 1.0,
 'month_id': None,
 'param1_value': 3.0,
 'param2_value': 223.0,
 'param3_value': None,
 'param4_value': None,
 'param5_value': None,
 'formula_expression': 'param1+param2',
 'attrib_type': 'Actual',
 'derived_attrib_value': 226.0,
 'is_active': True}
```

Comment: It would be better to convert them to float, otherwise you are truncating values.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid true, I misinterpreted that they wanted specifically ints after reading your comment. Will amend.

Comment: Thanks !!  @BurhanKhalid, Agree with your point. I updated question too.